# how to Load Parameters from database when the application start and keep it in memory

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I need to load some data from a database table and save it in memory in order to be used when it's needed in the web applicaction. I'm using springboot and JPA/Hibernate. I guess the idea it's to run the query on boot and keep then on session or some kind of cache..

I'd like to know the apropiate way to do that and some examples if it's possible.

I did something similar but without spring and JPA and I'm not sure how to apply it here.

BTW, I'm pretty new on that (springboot and jpa/hibernate)
Thanks in advance

Comment: Would  [second level cache](https://www.javatpoint.com/hibernate-second-level-cache) work for you? As a less cumbersome alternative, you can use [`@Cacheable`](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cache-tutorial) on the service method loading the data

Answer (score 0):

There're many ways to achieve this like you can use PostConstruct to pull, use application bootstrap event, you can use a bean that implements SmartLifeCycle/Lifecycle.

PostContruct

```java
@Component
public class SomeService {
   
    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
      
     // pull data from JPA repository and store it
    }

}
```

Using Lifecycle interface

```java
@Component
public class SomeService implements Lifecycle{
   
    @Override
    public void start(){
       // pull data using JPA and store it
    }
    //...

}
```

Using  ApplicationReadyEvent listener

```java
@Component
public class SomeService implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent>  {
   
  @Override
  public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationReadyEvent event) {
     // pull data using JPA and store it
  }
}
```

You can use other combinations as well.

Comment: What about using ehcache?

Comment: You can use that as well, it's up to you decide where to store this data, either in local system memory or remote machine.